# run additional php code in echo after replacing strings

Tags: php, echo

i want to execute addition php code after replacing some string from form

here os my form code on form.php

```
<form method="post" action="result.php">
<input type="text" name="yourtext">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

and for example the text is

```
my name is bagu and i live under a rock thanks
```

here the result.php code

```
<?php

$mytext = $_POST['yourtext'];

$find = ["my name is","and i live", "thanks"];

$replace = ["<?php open_form('Form/insert') ?><input name='name' type='text' value='","'><br><input name='address' type='text' value='","'><input type='submit'><?php form_close() ?>"];

$intoform = str_replace($find, $replace, $mytext);

echo $intoform;

?>
```

the result i want is to the "bagu" and "under a rock" each in a textbox which is working

but the trouble is the form php code in echo is not working (i think??? because it is)

and yes this is form for codeigniter

thanks

======

edit: i have tried the result.php without echo and variable aka the result i wanted after i submit text in form.php

```
<?php open_form('Form/insert') ?>
<input name='name' type='text' value='bagu'><br>
<input name='address' type='text' value='under a rock'>
<input type='submit'>
<?php form_close() ?>
```

and it will work if "<?php" changed to "<?= "
idk if this helps tho

=====

edit 2:

aaand if i input

```
my name is bagu and i live under a rock thanks my name is ariel and i live under the sea thanks my name is snow white and i live under a pumpkin thanks
```

i will have 3 forms

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. You just need to extract a few words from the string, this can be done with [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). Are you learning how to use `str_replace` or do you just not know how to implement this function?

Comment: I agree with shingo. It's highly unlikely you'll be using the code in your question. What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i want to make kind of confirmation form based of text that submited before save it to database

Comment: OK, I think I somewhat know what you mean. You want to extract two pieces out of the submitted text and create a new form out of that. For the example text that would be a form with two text inputs with the values: _" is bagu "_, and: _" under a rock "_. I would suggest to start with a form with two inputs: One of the the name and one for the address of the user. That would make everything a lot simpler.

Comment: In case you still want to extract the name and the address from one input string, then just do that and use what you've extracted in a next step to create the confirmation form. What you're currently doing with `str_replace()` is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Extract the name and address using [`preg_match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). The die clause is just used to indicate input string formatting errors and can be replaced with more friendly prompts as needed.

   ```
   preg_match('/my name is (.+) and i live (.+) thanks/', $mytext, $m)
   or die('Input text is invalid');
   ```
2. If `preg_match` succeeds, `$m[1]` will contain the name, and `$m[2]` will contain the address, then you can insert the values into the form

   ```
   <?php open_form('Form/insert') ?>
   <input name='name' type='text' value='<?=$m[1]?>'><br>
   <input name='address' type='text' value='<?=$m[2]?>'>
   <input type='submit'>
   <?php form_close() ?>
   ```

- It should be added that in actual practice, the legality of the name and address entered by the user should be checked. For example to restrict them to only contain letters and spaces, the regex `(.+)` in the first step can be changed to `([A-Za-z ]+)`.

---

To match the text multiple times, use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`

```
preg_match_all('/my name is (.+?) and i live (.+?) thanks/', $mytext, $m)
or die('Input text is invalid');
```

Each matched item will now contain multiple values, then you can wrap the original output in foreach to output multiple forms

```
<?php foreach($m[0] as $i => $_):
open_form('Form/insert') ?>
<input name='name' type='text' value='<?=$m[1][$i]?>'><br>
<input name='address' type='text' value='<?=$m[2][$i]?>'>
<input type='submit'>
<?php form_close()
endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: now i get why yall confused! added an edit

Comment: You can use `preg_match_all` instead of `preg_match`.